# A problem in using boundary condition in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

The general solution of the heat equation is
$$X(x) = a \sin \omega x + b \cos \omega x$$

For the boundary conditions of
$$X(0) = 0\\
X(L) = 0$$
we will have $b=0$ and $a \sin \omega L$. Therefore the solution is
$$u_n(x,t)=e^{-n^2\pi^2kt/L^2} \sin(n\pi x/L)$$

---

Although it is unnecessary, but it is not incorrect to interpret the above boundary condisions as
$$X'(0) = 0\\
X'(L) = 0$$
By applying new boundary conditions in
$$X'(L) = \omega (-a \cos \omega L + b \sin \omega L)$$
we will have 
$$X(x) = a \cos(n \pi x/L)$$
and then the general solution leads to 
$$u_n(x,t)=e^{-n^2\pi^2kt/L^2} \cos(n\pi x/L)$$

***What is the reason for this difference?***

The reason that I am asking this question is that the first approach is the solution for the Dirichlet boundaries and the second for the Neumann boundaries. If we have a mix of Dirichlet-Neumann boundaries, which approach should be used? Shouldn't we get the same result by both approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citation :

> Although it is unnecessary, but it is not incorrect to interpret the above boundary condisions as
>   $$X'(0) = 0\\
> X'(L) = 0$$

No, it is incorrect.

$\begin{cases}X(0)=0\\X(L)=0\end{cases}\quad$ are different boundary conditions from $\quad\begin{cases}X'(0)=0\\X'(L)=0\end{cases}\quad$

With different boundary conditions, it is not surprising to obtain different solutions.